# Why is my sorting algorithm producing an infinite loop? C#

Tags: c#, sorting

ok, decided I would mess around and create a very basic Bubble sorting algorithm, I have only spent a couple hours, and this is only my second iteration of the program, and I'm kind of burnt out right now, and I seem to have hit a bit of a wall. I have it designed so that it will produce and display an Integer based on the number of transpositions it made on each round of sorting ( so I can keep an eye on it and make sure it is trending downward) and it is stuck in an infinite loop, returning the value '36' constantly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool sorted = false;
            int[] data = new int[100];
            data = GenerateData(data);

            while (sorted == false)
            {
                int count = Sort(data);
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    sorted = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", count);
                }
            }
        }

        public static int[] GenerateData(int[] data)
        {
            Random num = new Random();

            for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
            {
                data[x] = num.Next(0, 99);
            }
            return data;
        }

        public static int Sort (int[] data)
        {
            int TempA = 0;
            int TempB = 101;
            int count = 0;

            for (int x =0; x<100; x++)
            {
                TempA = data[x];

                if ((x + 1) < 100)
                {
                    TempB = data[(x + 1)];
                }

                else
                {
                    TempB = 101;
                }

                if ( TempA > TempB)
                {
                    data[x++] = TempA;
                    data[x] = TempB;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a situation where a good debugger would be useful

Comment: Would really help if you added comments to your Sort method, to explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish. A lot is hard coded which actually makes it harder for me to parse what you're actually doing.

Comment: didn't think about that, at time of writing it. comments would be very helpful.

Comment: didn't think about that, at time of writing it. comments would be very helpful. Its supposed to start at the first index value, compare it to the second index value, if the first index value is larger it switches the two, then it just incriments

Comment: Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint and step through the code. See what's causing the problem. We're not a code debugging service. Stepping through code in a debugger to see how and why things are happening is an essential part of writing code. Learn to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong with these two lines

```
data[x++] = TempA;
data[x] = TempB;
```

It should either be

```
data[x++] = TempA;
data[x--] = TempB;
```

Or

```
data[x+1] = TempA;
data[x] = TempB;
```

Otherwise your `for` loop will end up skipping elements.

Comment: Exceptionally good catch there, I just realized I am incrementing the actual index value, not just referencing it for the code. I will change it now, as you suggest. However I doubt that that will solve it all

Comment: well sir, You might have fixed it entirely. Imm far too tired to check it all out. But I feel like you did it. it is no longer infinitely looping

Comment: It looks like you just want to swap the values. I'm pretty sure C# has a function for doing just that. Even if it doesn't you can just write a simple swap for this exercise.

Comment: There is an array sort method, but the point of this is to do it manually